# How to map MongoDB data in Spark for kmeans?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, k-means

I want to run k-means within Spark on data provided from a MongoDB. 
I have a working example which acts against a flatfile:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="KMeansExample")  # SparkContext
data = sc.textFile("/home/mhoeller/kmeans_data.txt")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([int(x) for x in line.split(' ')]))
clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 2, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="random")
```

this is the format of the flatfile is:

0 0 1
1 1 1
2 2 2
9 9 6

Now I want to replace the flatfile with a MongoDB:

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/ycsb.usertable") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb:/127.0.0.1/ycsb.usertable") \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/ycsb.usertable").load()

# <<<< Here I am missing the parsing >>>>>

clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 2, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="random")
```

**I like to understand how to map data from the df so that it can be used as input for kmeans.**

The "layout" of the database is:
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field0: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field1: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field3: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field4: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field5: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field6: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field7: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field8: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field9: binary (nullable = true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like to understand how to map data from the df so that it can be used as input for kmeans.

Based on your snippet, I assumed that you're using PySpark.

If you look into [clustering.KMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeans) Python API doc, you can see that the first parameter needs to be `RDD of Vector or convertible sequence types`

After you performed below code which load data from MongoDB using [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/)

```py
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
               .option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/ycsb.usertable")
               .load()
```

What you have in `df` is a DataFrame, so we need to convert it into something convertible to a Vector type.

Since you are using [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) in your text file example, we can keep using this array type for learning transition.

Based on the provided `layout`, firstly we need to remove the `_id` column as it won't be needed for the clustering training. See also [Vector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#local-vector) data type for more information.

With the above information, let's get into it:

```py
# Drop _id column and get RDD representation of the DataFrame
rowRDD = df.drop("_id").rdd

# Convert RDD of Row into RDD of numpy.array
parsedRdd = rowRDD.map(lambda row: array([int(x) for x in row]))

# Feed into KMeans 
clusters = KMeans.train(parsedRdd, 2, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="random")
```

If you would like to keep the boolean value (True/False) instead of integer (1/0), then you can remove the `int` part. As below:

```
parsedRdd = rowRDD.map(lambda row: array([x for x in row]))
```

Putting all of them together :

```py
from numpy import array 
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/ycsb.usertable") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb:/127.0.0.1/ycsb.usertable") \
.getOrCreate()

df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()

rowRDD = df.drop("_id").rdd
parsedRdd = rowRDD.map(lambda row: array([int(x) for x in row]))

clusters = KMeans.train(parsedRdd, 2, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="random")
clusters.clusterCenters
```